# Why does Frame.tryValues fail in this simple example?

Tags: f#, deedle

The help for `Frame.tryValues` has the following:

"Given a data frame containing columns of type `tryval<'T>`, returns a new data frame that contains the underlying values of type `'T`."

I interpreted this as meaning that the function would strip the type `tryval` from values and return those stripped values. Maybe I did not understand the text because the function fails in the following case:

```
let dates  = 
  [ DateTime(2013,1,1); 
    DateTime(2013,1,2); 
    DateTime(2013,1,3) ]

let values = [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]

let first = Series(dates, values)

let frame = Frame(["first"], [first])

let f (dt: DateTime) (row: ObjectSeries<string>) = row.Get("first") :?> double

let s =
    frame
    |> Frame.tryMapRows f

// frame1's second column has tryvalues
let frame1 = Frame(["first"; "second"], [first; s])
// frame2 has no tryvalues
let frame2 = Frame(["first"; "second"], [first; first])

let frame3 =
    frame1
    |> Frame.tryValues
// fails

let frame3 =
    frame2
    |> Frame.tryValues
// Ok, works fine
```

Why does the first call to `Frame.tryValues` above fail but the second does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in Deedle. I looked into it and [submitted a PR with a fix](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/pull/359).

Comment: I think `Deedle` is the best thing since sliced bread (in the `F#` universe). And I am proud to have contributed a tiny bit to its improvement. Many thanks.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at `SO 42912346`. I suspect a bug there.